# SQLite data cleanup in Windows 8 application

Tags: sqlite, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

In my windows 8.1 application i am using SQLitePCL on top of SQLite.

I create the tables and populate my test data on application launch.

I only create DB tables if the tables are not existing through SQL is exists keyword in the queries.

Now how do i clean up the populated test data. Do i have to run delete queries when application shuts down ?.

I am testing through Windows simulator 8. Is there no way to clean up the app data which will flush the db in the simulator ?

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to recreate DB schema every time you need to flush populated data. You have at least two options to achieve that:

**At first**: in the same way as you create DB tables if they are not exist, you can delete DB when the data should be flushed and recreate it. I use this code to open/create DB file.

```
private async Task<bool> IsDBExistAsync()  
{
    bool isExist = true;
    try
    {
        StorageFile sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(DATABASE_NAME);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        isExist = false;
    }
    return isExist;
}
```

**At second**: open explorer window and navigate to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{package_family_name}\LocalState` and delete DB file manually when it is not needed anymore. "package_family_name" is specified in Package.appxmanifest of your app (Packaging tab).

**Bonus item**: if you are developing phone part - you can access local storage using [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) utility.